# How to create a visualisation using seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I've loaded the data from a csv file in Jupyter notebook. After cleaning and imputing the dataframe I'm trying to plot some visualisations. However I'm not sure if I'll need to create a pivot table for that or change the data type of few columns.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Items'[GDP, GDP, 0],
    'Duration':[2013-2014, 2014-2015,0],
    'Assam':[177745.00,198745.00,12.07],
    'Bihar': [317101.00,373101.00,10.87],
    'Delhi':[443783.00,492783.00,8.84],
    'Goa':[35921.00,40921.00,6.24],
    'Total':[974550.00,1074550.00,9.0]
})
```

I've got the mean value by `data11.loc[10] = data11.loc[7:9].mean()`

I've already tried transposing the dataframe and then using it for plotting graphs with `df.T`.

Items and duration column is in non-null object dtype whereas rest of them are in non-null float dtype.

I'm trying to plot a bar chart with the name of states (Assam, Bihar, Goa and Delhi) along with their mean values (12.07, 10.87, 8.84 and 6.24). What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Try to give the data in a dataframe constructor and specify precisely what you want to accomplish with that data.

Comment: This is an example of a Dataframe constructor: pd.DataFrame({'items': [1, 2], 'duration': [1, 2]}) it then enables you to copy paste and run the code.

Comment: pd.DataFrame({'Items'[GDP, GDP, 0],'Duration':[2013-2014, 2014-2015,0],'Assam':[177745.00,198745.00,12.07],'Bihar':[317101.00,373101.00,10.87],'Delhi':[443783.00,492783.00,8.84],'Goa':[35921.00,40921.00,6.24],'Total':[974550.00,1074550.00,9.0]})

Answer (score 0):

You can plot straight from `Pandas` like:

```
df[['Assam', 'Bihar', 'Delhi', 'Goa']].loc[2].plot(kind='bar')
```

Or if there are multiple regions:

```
colums = ['Items', 'Duration', 'Total']
df.drop(columns, axis=1).loc[2].plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: What if there are 30 instances like Assam? Is there a shorter way to do the same?